# ASP.NET regex validator trim

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have `^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d).*$` regex pattern for regular expression validator. 
How can I change validator to forbid white spaces at the start and end of string.

Comment: What do you mean? You already ARE forbidding white space with that regular expression?

Comment: Sorry, my regex is ^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d).*$

Comment: Can you have spaces in the middle of the string? Also, what kind of strings are you trying to validate exactly?

Comment: Yes spaces are allowed in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^\S(?=.*\d)(?=.{10,})(.*\S)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your regex to this:

```
^\S*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)\S*$
```

`\S` means anything but a whitespace character.

Comment: There is a problem, that white spaces are not allowed in the middle of string.

Comment: [Word123 456]           without spaces at the start or end of string

Comment: [Word123 456] should match or should not match?

Comment: Should match. If white spaces are at the start or end of string, then should not match.

Comment: ^\S(?=.*\d)(?=.{10,})(.*\S)?$

Comment: If it works perfectly for you then you may post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\s*(.*)\s*$? \s*(.*)
```